# How do I draw a 3D truncated pyramid in Python(with user-inputs)?

Tags: python

i'm relatively new with python and have been trying to create a small program, that draws a truncated pyramid based on the larger and smaller base, and the height, by inputs from the user. But every time, i plot the drawing, the smaller base is not centered.

I would very appreciate it, if someone could point out the mistake in my code.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d import Poly3DCollection, Line3DCollection
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

G = 4
g = 2
h = 2

a = math.sqrt(math.pow(h,2)+math.pow((((G/2)-(g/2))),2))
Z = np.array([[-1, -1, -1],
                  [(-1+G), -1, -1 ],
                  [(-1+G), (-1+G), -1],
                  [-1, (-1+G), -1],
                  [(-1+(a/3)), (-1+(a/3)), (-1+h)],
                  [(-1+(a/3)+g), (-1+(a/3)), (-1+h)],
                  [(-1+(a/3)+g), (-1+(a/3)+g), (-1+h)],
                  [(-1+(a/3)), (-1+(a/3)+g), (-1+h)]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1, projection='3d')

r = [-1,1]

X, Y = np.meshgrid(r, r)
ax.scatter3D(Z[:, 0], Z[:, 1], Z[:, 2])

faces = [[Z[0],Z[1],Z[2],Z[3]],
 [Z[4],Z[5],Z[6],Z[7]],
 [Z[0],Z[1],Z[5],Z[4]],
 [Z[2],Z[3],Z[7],Z[6]],
 [Z[1],Z[2],Z[6],Z[5]],
 [Z[4],Z[7],Z[3],Z[0]],
 [Z[2],Z[3],Z[7],Z[6]]]

ax.add_collection3d(Poly3DCollection(faces,
 facecolors='cyan', linewidths=1, edgecolors='r', alpha=.25))

plt.show()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  You've posted your entire program, rather than the minimum needed to illustrate the problem.

Comment: Can you describe the logic behind the values of `Z` and `verts`?

Comment: @9000 The values of Z are supposed to be the points in the coordinate-system. There are a total of 8 values to form a quadrilateral shape, where the first four shapes the smaller base and the rest, the larger base. The actual idea with verts, was to represent the faces of the shape. E.g. connecting 4 points will form a face.